# Bootstrap 4 flex container to adjust to viewport size to create no wrap or overflow to next row?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

App (React + Bootstrap 4) looks good on medium viewport or higher, but in small/mobile, there is an overflow of the search bar and sort and it drops to the next "row" which is under the sidebar:

[What it looks like on mobile/small viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6mXa.png)

My code:

```
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <nav className="sidebar">
          <NavBar />
        </nav>
        <main
          role="main"
          className="col-md-9 mx-sm-auto mt-4 d-flex flex-nowrap"
        >
          <div className="col-md-9 flex-shrink-1">
            <SearchBar onSubmit={handleSearchSubmit(props.searchTerm)} />
          </div>
          <div className="flex-shrink-1">
            <DropDown />
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem yesterday with my navbar. I simply used media queries for width <= 320px which is small screen phones.